# What is a Battle.net account NID?

Tags: battle.net

When I try to make a Battle.net account, I'm asked to put in my NID. I have no idea what it means, and so don't know what to type in.

Comment: Battle.net accounts are region sensitive, it probably serves to tell people the location of your account.

Comment: By the way, NID is your National ID number. Seems to be a requirement for Asian accounts. Therefore my previous comment still stands.

Comment: @JamesJiao - **Battle.net accounts ARE NOT region sensitive.**

Comment: Yes they are. Some countries have additional fields and some don't have them. Btw, there is no need to shout. Calm down dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Jiao has said, NID means "National ID" and really only applies to Taiwan. Also, I've found that you can just leave it blank with no problem.

Comment: Where are you from? I'm 90% sure my account is a SEA account (Australia) and I never got this question setting up my account.

Comment: @MatthewScharley, I'm from Hong Kong.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Not all SEA accounts ask for NID. Only certain Asian countries like Taiwan and Hong Kong. I take it you didn't read my comments to your question.

Comment: @Russell - Just create a non-SEA account.

Comment: I've found you can ignore the NID box.

Answer (score 3):

First, Battle.net is divided into [two completely separate and distinct *partitions*](https://dev.battle.net/docs/read/concepts/Regionality), known as Worldwide and China, each of which has completely separate accounts and game servers. There is no connection whatsoever between the two partitions. An account on one partition does not exist on the other.

A Battle.net account exists within a *partition*.

Within each partition are *regions*. The regions are game-specific and so different games may use different regions. An account may play the same game in multiple regions, but will have different characters, achievements, etc., in each region, which do not transfer between regions.

The China partition has only one region, CN. In the Worldwide partition, there are multiple regions:

- World of Warcraft uses the US, EU, KR and TW regions.
- Diablo 3 uses the US, EU, KR and TW regions.
- StarCraft II uses the US, EU, KR, SEA and TW regions.

An account may authenticate to any region in the partition, but still play games in a different region in the same partition. The only benefit to authenticating to a different region is the possibility of reducing the latency of the login process.

---

With all that out of the way:

In China, Blizzard (actually, the operator NetEase) is required to ask for players' National ID numbers. Everyone in mainland China has such a number, so it is mandatory to provide one if you register an account in the China partition. (However, the last time I checked, Blizzard doesn't actually *verify* these numbers with the government, nor does it check the validity of the ID.) Due to the unique state of Taiwan's [political situation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taiwan), it does not use the same system of NID as China. The same is true about Hong Kong and Macau, where both places have separate ID systems.
As such, it is optional to provide the NID if you register an account in the Worldwide partition.