# Can I play on EU servers I register on US servers?

Tags: overwatch, battle.net

I told someone who is in the US to get me 2 $20 Blizzard gift cards because they don't have Overwatch where I live, nor the Blizzard gift cards.

But for some reason when I signed up I turned out to be a EU account. So I'm busted.
I'm going to try using VPN to the US and create another account. But I'm afraid that if I get a US account in won't be able to play on the EU servers, but only on the US servers. My ping will be literally over 900. Would I be able to play on the EU servers?

Comment: [Related](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/257563/32008)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Progress is separated by regional server for Blizzard games on Battle.net. So you can play the game on US or EU servers but progress and purchases within the game are only available on the server you bought them on or progressed on. You should be able to contact Blizzard to move your account's purchases and progress to another server.

Comment: Nevermind that, I ended up creating a new account anyways because there was nothing on it. Thanks for the info!

Comment: What's more, you can choose which region you're playing in from the Blizzard client... or whatever the name is this week (Blizzard Battle.Net?)  Overwatch regions listed on my (US) account are: Americas, Europe, Asia, and Public Test Region.